# XCode4 Base class in property gives compiler warning when set to subclass

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4

I have a base class, say BaseClass, which provides a common interface for several subClasses, defined by, for example @interface SubA:BaseClass.

The interface of the base class includes a method, say -(void)method1:arg;

In my view, I want to send message to different subClass instances, depending on circumstances.  View has a property something like

```
@property (strong) BaseClass *currentInstance
```

When I use, in a controller object,

```
[self.myView setCurrentInstance:instanceOfSubA]
```

I get a compiler warning.

Then in the view at some point I have

```
[self.currentInstance method1:thisArg]
```

and everything works right; that is:

Checking the class in the view, gives the class as SubA.
And all the overridden functions give the right results.

Can I get rid of the warnings?  Or is this a signal that I'll get in trouble somewhere down the line.

Comment: Are you sure that setCurrentInstance is a method of your UIView subclass, and not of the view controller?

Comment: Yes. It is a method of my NSView subclass.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this should work. What warning did you get?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the answer in [Cocoa With Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/polymorphism-is-always-wrong-word.html)

In his description of why not to say "polymorphic" Matt Gallagher gives this example of overriding:

```
  MyBaseClass *newObject = [[[MySubClass alloc] init] autorelease];
 [newObject instanceMethodDeclaredInMyBaseClass];
```

Tried it, and it works.  Simple and straight forward, but I wouldn't have thought of it if I hadn't seen this example.

By the way, I've benefited from Cocoa With Love many times.